# How to check if a string stored in a variable is the same as an ip address from netstat -nao in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, netstat

This is my first time asking a question so try not to be to hard on me.

I am competing in a small capture the flag event and am writing some simple batch scripts to help out a bit.

The purpose of program is to check if output from `netstat -nao` is in the `dontkill` variable. If it is, then don't kill it; if it is not, then look for the process id and kill the connection. `dontkill` will contain my IP address so that it doesn't kill my remote connection to the computer.

Seems pretty simple, but I have had major trouble because I don't know how to write in batch very well.

Here is my code so far:

```
for /L %%i in (1,0,) do @for /f "tokens=5" %%j in ('netstat -nao ^| findstr ^"ESTABLISHED^"' ) do @taskkill /f /PID %%j
```

This goes through and looks for any ESTABLISHED connections and kills them in an infinite loop. I have tried many different variations of this command, and I recognize that I need some sort of a `if/else` statement in the second do to check if `dontkill` is the same as what is stored in the variable `%%a` in the loop:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in('"netstat -nao^|findstr ^"ESTABLISHED^"')
```

I know this would probably be easier in some other scripting language but it has to be batch because the computers I will be using it on will be fresh install Windows XP, Server 2003, 2008 and Win7.

Ok with the for loop directly above the variable a is carrying output like this "192.168.1.230:1003" so it has the ip address and also the port separated by a colon.

I need to be able to compare it to the variable dontkill which only has the Ip address.

Is there any way to get rid of the :1003 so that I can compare it to the variable dontkill.

I have been messing around with things such as

```
SET line="192.168.1.241:10256"
SET string3=%line::[0-9]*=%
```

but it doesn't work.

So to be clear I'm trying to go from "192.168.1.241:10256" to "192.168.1.241" so that I can compare the final result to dontkill and decide what to do.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Sudo code
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
DONTKILL = "192.168.1.241"

FOR(NUMBER OF PROCESSES FILTERED BY FINDSTR. LOOK AT COLUMN 3 AND 5)

```
VAR A IS THE COLUMN 3 INFO which is some ip address with port "192.168.1.241:1003"

VAR B IS THE COLUMN 5 INFO which is PID "1524"

IF(DONTKILL == A)

    DONTKILL THAT PROCESS
ELSE
    KILL THAT PROCESS USING 
    TASKKILL /F /PID B
```

I got the inspiration for this method from http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/2010/01/episode-76-say-hello-to-my-little.html

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but I wrote a batch script to parse netstat output: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26839729/1569434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "DONTKILL=127.0.0.1"

for /f "tokens=1-5 delims= " %%a in ('netstat -nao ^| find /i "ESTABLISHED"' ) do (
echo [%%a] [%%b] [%%c] [%%d] [%%e]
call:GetIP %%c

if !$IP!==%DONTKILL% (
echo IP !$IP! IS EQUAL TO DONTKILL [%DONTKILL%] 
echo.
) else (
echo IP !$IP! IS NOT EQUAL TO DONTKILL [%DONTKILL%]
echo.
)
)
exit/b

:GetIP
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('echo %1') do (
set "$IP=%%a"
goto:eof)
```

Comment: Ok i've revised some of my question. Thanks for the speedy answer. In your post if you compare %%j and %%k what you are really comparing is example ip"192.168.1.130:10000" == PID"54133". Is this correct or am I missing something.

Comment: Yes that's it. Check the new code to anderstand. I don't now what you're trying to test but this should help.

Comment: Ok hey i added some sudo code to my question. Thanks for the help

Comment: Dude you are awesome to no end Thank you so much.