# Parsing NETSTAT -ban switches in batch

Tags: parsing, batch-file, netstat

Extensive searches found no solution in batch to parse `netstat -bano` (same switch as `-nab`, `-bna`, `-anb`, `-nba`, `nabo`, etc.) so all info from a given network connection is on the *same line*.

`Netstat`'s `-ban` switches are used to:

-b = display executable

-a = display all connections and listening ports

-n = display addresses and ports in numerical form.

-o = display owning process ID for each connection (i.e., PID)

But netstat adds the file name to the *next* line, making processing the output very difficult. Extensive searches didn't find any answers in batch.

I created a way to parse it by looking for a ] (right bracket) as the last character on a line. If it is a ], then basically output the "combined" line, which now contains the executable.

My code is posted as an answer, but does an ugly job since it has to use files to handle the parsing instead of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created solution in batch to concatenate all output for a given connection so it's on one line. Save script (below) as a batch file and when run it will create a file called "NETSTAT--%computername%.txt" in the same folder as the script, where %computername% will be replaced with the hostname of computer it's run on.

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal
REM Method of finding last character-of-a-string-from-a-variable
REM http://stackoverflow.com/a/15662607/1569434

REM Get the script's path so all needed files can sit in the same folder
SET SCRIPTPATH=%~p0
CD %SCRIPTPATH%

REM Read and pass each line in file one at a time to sub 'FindEXE'
SET CONCATLINE=
SET HEADERROW=
SET /A LINECOUNT = 0
@echo LINECOUNT = %LINECOUNT%
del %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat*.txt /q 2>nul

netstat -bano>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat0.txt
REM Copy all lines except those with "TIME_WAIT" into text file
FINDSTR /V /I /C:"TIME_WAIT" %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat0.txt>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat1.txt
REM Delete first two lines, which are a header and a blank line
for /f "skip=2 delims=*" %%a in (%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat1.txt) do (echo %%a>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat2.txt)

REM Search for and process file based on matching text
REM This sub begins putting each netstat connection on one line
for /f "delims=*" %%A in (%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat2.txt) do call :FindTXT1 %%A

REM netstat3 will have all data from given connection on one line
SET /A LINECOUNT = 0
for /f "delims=*" %%A in (%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat3.txt) do call :FindTXT2 %%A

REM Keep only header and unique (i.e., those with "[::]") 'listening' connections
FINDSTR /I /C:"LISTENING" /C:"Local Address" %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.TXT>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat5.TXT
FINDSTR /I /C:"[::]:" /C:"Local Address" %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat5.TXT>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat6.TXT

MOVE /Y %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat6.txt %SCRIPTPATH%\NETSTAT--%computername%.txt
del %SCRIPTPATH%netstat*.txt /q 2>nul
@echo off

echo done.

EndLocal
goto :EOF




:FindTXT1
REM We've got a line sent to us. Set variable to entire line using * (instead of %1)
SET CURRENTLINE=%*
SET /A LINECOUNT = %LINECOUNT% + 1
REM Add line feed after header row and return to main script
IF "%LINECOUNT%" == "1" (
    SET HEADERROW=%CURRENTLINE%
    @ECHO %CURRENTLINE%> %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat3.txt
    goto :eof
    )

REM Append a comma and CURRENTLINE to CONCATLINE. NOTE: Script expecting comma; don't use semi-colon
SET CONCATLINE=%CONCATLINE%,%CURRENTLINE%

REM When echo line, remove first char (comma, inserted above) using:
REM http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html
REM If last char is "]" then print, otherwise append
IF "%CURRENTLINE:~-1%"=="]" (
    REM @echo right bracket=FOUND
    @echo %CONCATLINE:~1%>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat3.txt
    SET CONCATLINE=
        ) else (
    REM @echo right bracket=NOT found
    )

REM If line = "Can not obtain ownership information" then print, otherwise append
IF "%CURRENTLINE%"=="Can not obtain ownership information" (
    REM @echo No Ownership=TRUE
    @echo %CONCATLINE:~1%>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat3.txt
    SET CONCATLINE=
    )

goto :eof


:FindTXT2
REM We've got a line sent to us. Set variable to entire line using * (instead of %1)
SET CURRENTLINE=%*
SET /A LINECOUNT = %LINECOUNT% + 1
REM Add line feed after header row and return to main script
IF "%LINECOUNT%" == "1" (
    SET HEADERROW=%CURRENTLINE%
    @ECHO %CURRENTLINE%> %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
    goto :eof
    )

REM If last char is "]" then search, otherwise append.
REM Without "DelayedExp...", variable sets to value from previous FOR loop
IF "%CURRENTLINE:~-1%"=="]" (
    SetLocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    REM IP6 EXEs result in 3 sets of [], so find and set var to last one, which is where EXE lives
    FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=[]" %%a in ("%CURRENTLINE%") do (
        SET BINNAME1=%%b
        SET BINNAME2=%%f
        IF "!BINNAME1!" == "::" (
            REM @ECHO BINNAME1=!BINNAME1!>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
            SET BINNAME=!BINNAME2!
            REM @echo %CURRENTLINE%;BINNAME=!BINNAME2!>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
            ) else (
            SET BINNAME=!BINNAME1!
            REM @echo %CURRENTLINE%;BINNAME=!BINNAME1!>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
            )
        @echo %CURRENTLINE%;BINNAME=!BINNAME!>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
        )
    ) else (
    @echo %CURRENTLINE%>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
    SetLocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
)

goto :eof
```

Answer (score 4):

The previous version of this script was missing a backslash. Additionally the script would delete the output file. Creating the file as %computername%--NETSTAT.txt instead of NETSTAT--%computername%.txt fixes the problem.

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal
REM Method of finding last character-of-a-string-from-a-variable
REM http://stackoverflow.com/a/15662607/1569434

REM Get the script's path so all needed files can sit in the same folder
SET SCRIPTPATH=%~p0
CD %SCRIPTPATH%

REM Read and pass each line in file one at a time to sub 'FindEXE'
SET CONCATLINE=
SET HEADERROW=
SET /A LINECOUNT = 0
@echo LINECOUNT = %LINECOUNT%
del %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat*.txt /q 2>nul

netstat -bano>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat0.txt
REM Copy all lines except those with "TIME_WAIT" into text file
FINDSTR /V /I /C:"TIME_WAIT" %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat0.txt>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat1.txt
REM Delete first two lines, which are a header and a blank line
for /f "skip=2 delims=*" %%a in (%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat1.txt) do (echo %%a>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat2.txt)

REM Search for and process file based on matching text
REM This sub begins putting each netstat connection on one line
for /f "delims=*" %%A in (%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat2.txt) do call :FindTXT1 %%A

REM netstat3 will have all data from given connection on one line
SET /A LINECOUNT = 0
for /f "delims=*" %%A in (%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat3.txt) do call :FindTXT2 %%A

REM Keep only header and unique (i.e., those with "[::]") 'listening' connections
FINDSTR /I /C:"LISTENING" /C:"Local Address" %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat5.txt
FINDSTR /I /C:"[::]:" /C:"Local Address" %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat5.txt>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat6.txt

MOVE /Y %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat6.txt %SCRIPTPATH%\%computername%--NETSTAT.txt
del %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat*.txt /q 2>nul
@echo off

echo done.

EndLocal
goto :EOF




:FindTXT1
REM We've got a line sent to us. Set variable to entire line using * (instead of %1)
SET CURRENTLINE=%*
SET /A LINECOUNT = %LINECOUNT% + 1
REM Add line feed after header row and return to main script
IF "%LINECOUNT%" == "1" (
    SET HEADERROW=%CURRENTLINE%
    @ECHO %CURRENTLINE%> %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat3.txt
    goto :eof
    )

REM Append a comma and CURRENTLINE to CONCATLINE. NOTE: Script expecting comma; don't use semi-colon
SET CONCATLINE=%CONCATLINE%,%CURRENTLINE%

REM When echo line, remove first char (comma, inserted above) using:
REM http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html
REM If last char is "]" then print, otherwise append
IF "%CURRENTLINE:~-1%"=="]" (
    REM @echo right bracket=FOUND
    @echo %CONCATLINE:~1%>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat3.txt
    SET CONCATLINE=
        ) else (
    REM @echo right bracket=NOT found
    )

REM If line = "Can not obtain ownership information" then print, otherwise append
IF "%CURRENTLINE%"=="Can not obtain ownership information" (
    REM @echo No Ownership=TRUE
    @echo %CONCATLINE:~1%>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat3.txt
    SET CONCATLINE=
    )

goto :eof


:FindTXT2
REM We've got a line sent to us. Set variable to entire line using * (instead of %1)
SET CURRENTLINE=%*
SET /A LINECOUNT = %LINECOUNT% + 1
REM Add line feed after header row and return to main script
IF "%LINECOUNT%" == "1" (
    SET HEADERROW=%CURRENTLINE%
    @ECHO %CURRENTLINE%> %SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
    goto :eof
    )

REM If last char is "]" then search, otherwise append.
REM Without "DelayedExp...", variable sets to value from previous FOR loop
IF "%CURRENTLINE:~-1%"=="]" (
    SetLocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    REM IP6 EXEs result in 3 sets of [], so find and set var to last one, which is where EXE lives
    FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=[]" %%a in ("%CURRENTLINE%") do (
        SET BINNAME1=%%b
        SET BINNAME2=%%f
        IF "!BINNAME1!" == "::" (
            REM @ECHO BINNAME1=!BINNAME1!>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
            SET BINNAME=!BINNAME2!
            REM @echo %CURRENTLINE%;BINNAME=!BINNAME2!>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
            ) else (
            SET BINNAME=!BINNAME1!
            REM @echo %CURRENTLINE%;BINNAME=!BINNAME1!>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
            )
        @echo %CURRENTLINE%;BINNAME=!BINNAME!>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
        )
    ) else (
    @echo %CURRENTLINE%>>%SCRIPTPATH%\netstat4.txt
    SetLocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
)

goto :eof
```